# Existing DB2 connection does not work inside a script

Tags: db2, scripting

I connected to the DB2 instance, and I can successfully verify that the connection exists:

```
db2inst1@hostname:/tmp$ db2 connect

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.3
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = DBNAME
```

However, when I run the following script

```
db2inst1@hostname:/tmp$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash 
db2 connect
```

the connection seems to disappear:

```
db2inst1@hostname:/tmp$ ./test.sh 
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
```

I wonder,

- What is reason for that?
- How to work in scripts with the existing connection?

Comment: Is bash the shell you're working in when you execute the command in-shell?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ, yes, I execute from `bash`. The following command also does not work: `bash ./test.sh`

Comment: A connection is local to its subshell; `./test.sh` runs in its own subshell.

Comment: Is there a problem making the connection from within the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio) points out in the [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175752/existing-db2-connection-does-not-work-inside-a-script#comment340433_175752), *a connection is local to its subshell*.

In order to [call the shell script in the context of the current shell](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1651414-Parent-shell-DB-connection-not-passed-to-sub-shell), `source` could be used:

```
db2inst1@hostname:/tmp$ source test.sh

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.3
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = DBNAME
```

Of course, `.` also works:

```
db2inst1@hostname:/tmp$ . test.sh

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.3
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = DBNAME
```